# python3 PyQt / PySide Linux installation

Tags: linux, python-3.x, installation, pyqt4, pyside

I've reinstalled python3.2.2 interpreter from source on Linux Mint to add unicode support in curses and found out that PyQt4 library is not importing. I've tried to reinstall it, but got the same problem as here: [PyQt4 for Python 3.2.2 failing to install on Linux Mint 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864906/pyqt4-for-python-3-2-2-failing-to-install-on-linux-mint-12). So I've followed the answer of **BlaXpirit** and installed PySide, but it wasn't importing too. Then I've found them both in  ***/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages*** that wasn't added to PYTHONPATH variable. I've added that dir and recieved next:

```
In [1]: import PySide
```

is okay, but:

```
In [2]: import PySide.QtCore
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1c10ffe6e7d7> in <module>()
----> 1 import PySide.QtCore

ImportError: No module named QtCore
```

and PyQt4:

```
In [3]: import PyQt4
In [4]: import PyQt4.QtCore
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-e7e95ffb1113> in <module>()
----> 1 import PyQt4.QtCore

ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so: undefined symbol:       PyUnicodeUCS4_AsLatin1String
```

In PySide directory content is:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      181 2012-04-23 23:58 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   783048 2012-04-24 02:16 phonon.cpython-32mu.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 2012-07-17 09:34 __pycache__
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2606568 2012-04-24 02:16 QtCore.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   379188 2012-04-24 02:16 QtDeclarative.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11298296 2012-04-24 02:16 QtGui.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   377804 2012-04-24 02:16 QtHelp.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   921720 2012-04-24 02:16 QtNetwork.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   370024 2012-04-24 02:16 QtOpenGL.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   266296 2012-04-24 02:16 QtScript.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    47608 2012-04-24 02:16 QtScriptTools.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   481964 2012-04-24 02:16 QtSql.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   152524 2012-04-24 02:16 QtSvg.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    93592 2012-04-24 02:16 QtTest.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   770644 2012-04-24 02:16 QtUiTools.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   570536 2012-04-24 02:16 QtWebKit.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   443944 2012-04-24 02:16 QtXml.cpython-32mu.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   236552 2012-04-24 02:16 QtXmlPatterns.cpython-32mu.so
```

In PyQt4:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1111 2012-07-02 13:39 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   13369 2012-07-02 13:39 pyqtconfig.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2267672 2012-07-02 13:39 QtCore.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  226468 2012-07-02 13:39 QtDeclarative.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  302208 2012-07-02 13:39 QtDesigner.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7362040 2012-07-02 13:39 QtGui.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  639832 2012-07-02 13:39 QtNetwork.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  248712 2012-07-02 13:39 QtOpenGL.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  187824 2012-07-02 13:39 QtScript.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   19964 2012-07-02 13:39 QtScriptTools.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    5508 2012-07-02 13:39 Qt.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  300872 2012-07-02 13:39 QtSql.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   85296 2012-07-02 13:39 QtSvg.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   28932 2012-07-02 13:39 QtTest.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  404432 2012-07-02 13:39 QtWebKit.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  158112 2012-07-02 13:39 QtXmlPatterns.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  301924 2012-07-02 13:39 QtXml.so
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root    4096 2012-07-02 13:39 uic
```

I've reinstalled python3 several times from repositories and python.org, from sources and binaries, and now I have 1 executable python3.2mu in ***/usr/bin*** and 3 (python3, python3.2, python3.2m) in ***/usr/local/bin***.
Help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved the problem with PyQt4 by changing 65 line in pyatomic.h:

from

```
 _Py_ANNOTATE_HAPPENS_BEFORE(address);
```

to

```
_Py_ANNOTATE_HAPPENS_BEFORE(address) (void)address;
```